# Powering arduino sensors - what resistor should I use?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, current, resistor

Recently I have asked a question, why my sensors do not work on external power supply ([link](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/45795/sensors-go-crazy-on-external-power)). I have found out, that I was limiting the current too much with the resistors. I have tried using two sensors:

- DHT22, rated at 1.5mA max ([picture of my module](https://img1.banggood.com/thumb/view/2014/xiemeijuan/07/SKU146979/SKU146979a.jpg))
- BH1750, rated at 190uA max ([picture of my module](https://www.mysensors.org/uploads/57cc6e4595afb8801e529dab/image/BH1750.jpg.png))

My logic is, if they are rated at that current, I should put a resistor in the Vin, to restrict the current to given value. But it turned out that I was wrong, because they started working only after I removed my resistors.

My questions is - should I put a resistor in there? If yes, then how do I know what resistance should I have, if the data sheet values are misleading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have NO resistor.

The datasheet states the current values the device will *pull* from the supply. Supplies DO NOT PUSH CURRENT.

Remove all resistors.

As long as the voltage is correct and the supply can provide *at least as much current as all devices combined want to use* then it will work.

Comment: And I was wondering, why every electrical component had clearly specified the operating voltage, but the current was somewhere below in the details section. That would explain things. Thank you!

Comment: 99% of components and devices require a specific voltage to operate, and the current varies depending on what it is doing at the time. The main exception is LEDs which have to have a specific current instead of a specific voltage.